# Android SQlite to json

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I have some data stored inside SQlite at my android application and I want to export it into json file and send it to a server via post HTTP. 
You can actually see my code in this link - [Old question containing my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692158/android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-near-create-record-table)

After searching the web, I'm only finding samples of doing it the other way around (from json to sqlite). I'll be happy to receive some help/push to the right direction.

Edit -

I get a small exeption while trying to initilise Gson - String json = gson.toJson(Record);
. Can you take a look please -

```
public ArrayList<Record> getAllRecordsArray() {
        ArrayList<Record> localList = new ArrayList<Record>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RECORD;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        //Loops through all rows and adds them to the local list
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                //Get record information
                Record record = new Record();
                record.setpLat(cursor.getDouble(0));
                record.setpLong(cursor.getDouble(1));
                record.setpAcc(cursor.getFloat(2));
                record.setpTime(cursor.getLong(2));
                //Add record  to list
                localList.add(record);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return localList;
    }

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(Record);
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722585/convert-sqlite-to-json

Comment: Thanks. when handling myPath=DB_PATH, How can I know my database path ?

Comment: The path where you created your database. By default its something like this `/data/data/com.me.myapp/databases/mydb.db` Or you can use `String dbname = "mydb.db";
Path dbpath = ctx.getDatabasePath(dbname);`

Answer (score 4):

Using the GSON library is by far the easiest way of handling it.

1) Initilize an ArrayList
2) Retrieve all the data from your database and store it in the ArrayList
3) Use gson.toJson(NameOfArrayList);
4) DONE. You now have a string containing all the data from your database.

Comment: Thanks you. Sounds indeed easy, but I have no experience with that. Can you provide an example please ? How can I insert the data from the SQlite into the ArrayList ?

Comment: I quickly put together this pastebin, with code snippets taken from one of my own projects:
http://pastebin.com/2WYDvyha

With that, you can get an ArrayList<Person> with all the data, then you can simply create a gson variable and use that:  
Gson gson = new Gson();  
String jsonString = gson.toJson(arrayList);

Comment: Thank you. I get a little exception, I added it to the main post. can you take a look please ?

Comment: There is absolutely no way for me to identify your problem if you don't post the actual exception message.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a library such as Gson? It allows you to easily convert a POJO (Plain old java object) to JSON.

You can simply get your object form your db and then do the following.

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

Its very useful, here is a link to the user guide:
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you, but it looks a bit too complicated for me.

Answer (score 0):

The below procedure could help ,

```
public JSONArray QueryAsJSON(String Query)
            throws org.json.simple.parser.ParseException {
        String out = "[";

        try {
            Cursor c = null;

            c = database.rawQuery(Query, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            String VergCol = "";

            for (int j = 0; j < c.getCount(); j++) {
                out += VergCol + "{";
                String vergRow = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < c.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    out += vergRow + "\"" + c.getColumnName(i) + "\"" + ":"
                            + "\"" + c.getString(i) + "\"";
                    vergRow = ",";
                }

                out += "}";
                VergCol = ",";
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        out += "]";

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        org.json.simple.JSONArray jsonArray = (org.json.simple.JSONArray) parser
                .parse(out);
        return jsonArray;

}
```

Comment: please don't ever do this.